# How do I Change The 'Leading' Color undependently from the AppBar color

Tags: flutter-appbar

Anybody has any idea How this leading background color container works. whenever I change The color of the container in the leading to (the one that I marked in red).It gives me a totally different color As you can see!! Why is that? And How can I fix it?
[Pictured Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi755.png)

`leading: Container( child: IconButton( icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.amber, size: 30), onPressed: () {}), color: Color(0xFFFFDEB4), ),`

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why you are not getting expected color. First of all try to adjust Container color's opacity:

```
leading: Container(
  child: IconButton(
   icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.amber, size: 30),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
  color: Color(0xFFFFDEB4).withOpacity(0.5), // Here is an example.
),
```

If it will not work, then remove container background color:

```
leading: IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.amber, size: 30),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

If any solutions helped, I suggest creating custom appbar. This way, you can design the desired layout and appearance more precisely.